# How to create a GridView.count inside of ListView in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart, gridview

I'm trying to implement this model.

[image: Grid View model]

I need to place this Grid view inside of ListView while I do so I've Caught up with some errors.

I need a Listview to make it scrollable with more grids.

```
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#f9839 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#f9839 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold 
lib\widgets\homePage.dart:14
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#f9839 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#f9839 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold 
lib\widgets\homePage.dart:14
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

This error shows up, this is just a part of the error. How to implement the gridview inside of listview in flutter.

The code I've tried is

```
body: ListView(
        children: [
          firstRow(),
        ],
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
      ),
```

The firstRow() function is

```
return GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30,left: 15),
        child: Card(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 227, 229, 100),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              ),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){},
                splashColor: Colors.red,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text('1', textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                          ),
                        ],
                  ),
                      ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          elevation: 3,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: The image you have shown is not gridView inside ListView, its just a gridView. So dont wrap the gridView with listView

Comment: @Bensal said right , you don't need a list view just use Grid view  and please see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORiTTaVY6mM

Answer (score 0):

change scrollDirection: Axis. Horizontal to Axis. Vertical

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**use this body directly to scaffold**

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate:
                    const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                ),
                itemCount: 20,
                primary: false,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 15),
                    child: Card(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 227, 229, 100),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        ),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          splashColor: Colors.red,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  '1',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      elevation: 3,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).